# Way to keep terminal as you left it when you open pycharm back up?

Tags: django

I'm new to programming and I'm working with django. The problem is when I close down Pycharm my terminal also closes.  When I open pycharm back up I have to to get my server back up and running each time.  Is there an option so that my terminal is exactly how I left it when I closed down Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to click on play and start the server instead of typing python manage.py runserver. Then you can do :

In Run -> Edit Configurations create new configuration
Script: path_to/manage.py
Script parameters: runserver